# Different space between \align and \equation

Tags: spacing, equations, align

Why produce the `align` and the `equation` environment different space between the text. And what can I do, that it have the same?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Long Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text

\begin{align}
 1+1=2
\end{align}

Again a long text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text

\begin{equation}
 1+1=2
\end{equation}

Another Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The calculations are a bit different so they are not always  same but the reason why the spacing is so bad in your example is that you should never have a blank line before a display math. The visible space is not (to TeX) a vertical space but a spurious extra paragraph with just an indentation box and parfillskip glue and no text making a blank line in addition to the intended space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Long Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text
\begin{align}
 1+1=2
\end{align}

Again a long text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text
\begin{equation}
 1+1=2
\end{equation}

Another Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

`equation` uses two possible spaces `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovediplayshortskip` depending on whether there is an overlap between the last row of the previous para and the equation. As far as I recall `align` doesn't do that (as essentially it's always full width internally even if visually smaller) you can stop equation closing up small cases with

```
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayshortskip=\abovedisplayskip
```

Or perhaps better if you want all displays to use a consistent AMS style, use `gather` instead of `equation`

Comment: Ok, the blank line before a display math make sense. But the Problem with the different space is still there.

Comment: @PeterP. updated with more suggestions:-)

Comment: it doesn't change the spacing, but `align` isn't mean to be used for on-line displays.