# Remove padding at top of page

Tags: spacing, margins

I am writing a paper using a collection of mandated styles. They add vertical spacing above things like equations and tables. However, if the item with padding is the very first item on a page, I am not supposed to have the padding. The instructions say to open it in a PDF editor and pull the content up on those pages.

Is there anything I can add that tells latex: Do not place any vertical spacing above anything when it is the first item on the page.

```
Given two object attribute vectors, such as $A$ and $B$ in Figure \ref{fig:triangle}; vector cosine defines similarity as the cosine of the angle, $\Theta$, $
Equation \ref{eq:vectorcosine} calculates vector cosine using ``dot product'' and ``magnitude'' vector operations.
The result will be -1 when the $\Theta$ is 180$^\circ$, 0 when $\Theta$ is 90$^\circ$, and 1 when $\Theta$ is 0$^\circ$.
Therefore, it is possible to infer that -1 means $A$ is opposite of $B$ while 1 means that $A$ is the same as $B$.

\begin{equation}
\textrm{S}(A,B) = \cos(\theta) = \frac{A\cdot B}{\left\Vert A\right\Vert \left\Vert B\right\Vert}
\label{eq:vectorcosine}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: That is the default behaviour, can you give an example where the space above an equation is not being discarded at the top of a page?

Comment: I added code of a paragraph so you can see how I separate it from the equation and what the equation code looks like. In one of the many buried cls files, it is placing about 3/4" spacing above the equation - which is OK in a page. When there's a page break after the paragraph, the 3/4" spacing is at the top of the page.

Comment: Never put a blank line before an equation that does not add vertical space (which is discarded automatically) it is an error that generaes a spurious blank horizontal box with just a paragraph indentation so it is not discarded. the class should set the length `\abovedisplayskip` to control space before an equation.

Comment: also use `$-1$` not `-1` in your text otherwise you get a little hyphen not a proper minus sign.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132965/different-space-between-align-and-equation/132971#132971

Comment: Thanks. I removed the blank line and the extra spacing at the top of the pages went away.

Comment: I thought it might:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertical space is always discarded at the start of a page but if the document has incorrect input consisting of blank lines before displayed math, then the "space" above the equation is not a vertical skip but is in fact a spurious single line paragraph, with the line consisting just if the indentation box and `\parfillskip` glue. As a horizontal box it is not discarded at the top of a page (and not stretchy within a page).